# Is there any option in firefox to not load non-SSL elements in a SSL-page?

Tags: firefox, security, iceweasel

When I have mixed content (SSL and non-SSL on a `https://` page), I would rather have a broken page than an insecure page.

Is there any way to disable the loading of non-SSL elements while on an https page?

Comment: this isn't really an issue the "non-secure" parts of a page are the static images ( logos etc. ) and have no reason to be encrypted.

Comment: @LamarB: It *can* be an issue if one of the insecure elements is a `<script>`, a good target for MITM attacks.

Comment: @grawity agreed, but if security is that big of an issue you should already have javascript disabled and selectively run the ones you need.

Comment: @LamarB: Well, first, many stores and banking sites require JavaScript. But the point I was trying to make is that without SSL, an attacker could replace a modify a script which you *do* need, and you wouldn't know it. You'd be thinking, "all scripts except this one are blocked, I'm safe".

Comment: it's exactly to confirm that "non-secure items are just logos" that i want an option to not load those. I don't need to see one store logo while i enter my credit card at checkout. But i'm sure as hell not buying there if i have to look at the source to see if it's really just the images and not the scripts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTTPS everywhere by the EFF may suit your needs it only supports a limited number of sites though. For non-supported sites you may need to find another option. https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere

On internet explorer 9 there is a "block unsecured images with other unsecured content" and a "display mixed content" enable/disable/prompt settings that should also help. Haven't found these type of settings for chrome or firefox yet but I would suspect that firefox's about:config would have similar settings.

Comment: the 2nd paragraph is mostly my question :) but thanks for the https-everywhere link! didn't know about that.

Answer (score 1):

Set the values of both of these about:config items to `true`:

- security.mixed_content.block_active_content
- security.mixed_content.block_display_content

Sources:

- [Mixed Content Blocking Enabled in Firefox 23!](https://blog.mozilla.org/tanvi/2013/04/10/mixed-content-blocking-enabled-in-firefox-23/)
- [Firefox 23 and mixed content](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/967115)